# Multiselect List in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where there is a need to display two multiselect list. Ex Continents and countries.

Upon selection of continent it will show all the countries belong to that continents and when selecting countries, it will display 4 columns of data in a pageblock.

Please share some snipets if anybody has.The UI will look as below - 
[image]

Regards
Sidhartha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this from @metadaddy

https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist